# Android SDK running slow

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

I have installed Android SDK on my computer. I have a intel i7-2600 processor and a Zotaxc 460 gtx fermi and 12 gb of ram. Basically saying, it shouldn't be running slow. Any suggestions on how to speed up the apis? or is it just slow?

Comment: Eclipse is just slow.  I've never gotten the emulator to work reasonably at all.

Comment: Are you talking about the emulator?  Because that is just slow.

Comment: ya, the emulator. I just wanted it to run faster and was wondering if i was doing anything wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to the Emulator and not Eclipse or something, you can speed up the Emulator a bit by choosing a smaller screen size for the virtual device, like HVGA instead of WVGA, etc.  But that only goes so far.  The emulator is just not very fast right now.  They are working on it, however.  I believe they show some of their early work in [this](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/android-development-tools.html) Google I/O session.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the AVD (the android device emulator) is running slowly, then it is behaving as expected. Perhaps you have an android device you can plug in and run your app on? I would recommend you download developer drivers for whatever device your using instead of the bloated ones they try to get you to download.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some usefull question that is about speed of android emulator:
[Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

Eclipse performance can by improved by setting `eclipse.ini`. For example I have set -Xms512m
-Xmx2048m. Without this options, Eclipse has too few memory to open my project.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the boot animation with `-no-boot-anim`, ["Disabling the boot animation can speed the startup time for the emulator."](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html)